# ¿QUE ES GITLAB y GITHUB?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

He encontrado que **Git**, **GitHub** y **GitLab** son buenas herramientas para proyectos que se estén desarrollando, pero después de haber buscado aun no comprendo cual es la verdadera función de gitlab, que es básicamente o un ejemplo de como usar **GitLab** en un proyecto de software.

Comment: Git es un sistema de versionamiento de software de código abierto,  Github y Gitlab son empresas que ofrecen una plataforma completa para versionar software apoyándose de git con lo cual múltiples desarrolladores pueden participar a la vez sin colisionar  o mal lograr el proyecto master, versión resumida

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es un problema de programación y casi que podría basarse en opiniones.

Comment: @Shaz Cierto que no es de programación (aunque no tengo yo tan claro que no tenga cabida en StackOverflow, al fin y al cabo hay una etiqueta `git`), pero en lo que no estoy de acuerdo es que esté basado en opiniones. La pregunta es "¿Qué son GitHub y GitLab?" y no "¿Cuál es mejor?"

Comment: @abulafia estás en tu derecho a no estar de acuerdo.

Comment: @Shaz Claro :-) Sólo intentaba hacerte cambiar de opinión :-)

Comment: @abulafia la etiqueta git se utilizar para problemas utilizando git.

Comment: git es la herramienta de versionado, podes montar un servidor git en tu servidor, o maquina local. pero para colaborar con otros suele ser mas cómodo abrirse una cuenta en un servidor en la nube, github, gitlab, bitbucket, sourceforge, gitkraken, launchpad son servidores del tipo freemium que favorecen el compartir código versionado. la mayoría incluye herramientas extra como webhooks, ci pipelines, teams, plantillas de licencias, conexión con bugtrackers o herramientas de administración onda jira etc...

Comment: Concuerdo con @gbianchi y Shaz , No es una pregunta de un problema en concreto. Las preguntas "que es", "para que sirve", "como se usa", etc. NO son preguntas que cumplan con las normas del sitio ni su finalidad. (Mi opinión)

Comment: @FranIslas yo aca no opine :p... aclare para que se utilizaba la etiqueta git. Uno puede preguntar para que sirve, pero si hizo averiguaciones y no le queda claro el que (en gral, si uno pone, averigue que hace tal cosa y tal otra, pero no entiendo porque si se puede hacer de otra forma) seria valida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la respuesta corta y rapida(y Muy incompleta ) es hacen lo mismo almacenan codigo y permiten llevar registro de los cambios y gestionar.

ahora si queres saber las diferencias que las hay y son importantes tenes que mirar este video aca lo explican muy bien y el tipo que explica te engancha.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EscDe0jG6XM

bien respuesta larga resumida: primero github es de codigo cerrado gitlab es open source github en principio era famoso por la funcion de pull request(mandarle pedazos de codigo al dueño) y perfiles de desarrolladores donde se podia ver que hace que.

pero las diferencias mas importantes son para los que estan enfocados a devops , mientras con github tenes que usar multiples herramientas para controlar todo el proceso del codigo

con gitlab puedes centralizar todo el proceso de desarrollo del codigo devops en una sola aplicacion ademas de añadido de una capa extra de seguridad necesaria cuando se utilizan tantas herramientas. una sola aplicacion para todo el ciclo ESA es la diferencia mas grande

Comment: no es necesario que borres tu respuesta y escribas otra.. alcanza con que la edites ;)

Comment: si la habia editado pero quedo mal por como estaba antes, asi me parece que se le puede hacer mas justicia. tuve que andar viendo bien la diferencia para que se note y ta la otra respuesta no era muy buena tenian razon

Answer (score 1):

**GitHub** y **GitLab** son un sistema de control de versiones, su función principal se define como control de versiones a la gestión de los diversos cambios que se realizan sobre los elementos de algún producto.

*Por ejemplo*: Tú código se almacena en un repositorio y cada cambio que hagas al código se genera una versión esto por si en algún momento deja de funcionar tu aplicación y no sabes que le moviste, puedes regresar a una versión anterior estable.

**Git**
Es el Software que maneja el control de versiones del código fuente, permitiéndole realizar y rastrear cambios de archivos locales y compartir cambios con un repositorio remoto.

**GitHub** (es decir, https://github.com/ )
Un servicio en la nube para el alojamiento remoto de repositorios git.

**GitLab** (es decir, https://gitlab.com/ )
Es un servicio en la nube muy parecido a GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Git es un sistema de **control de versiones distribuido**.

**Control de versiones** significa que va guardando (cuando tú se lo pides) una copia de cómo está la carpeta de trabajo en una especie de "histórico" que te permite ver cómo evolucionó, recuperar versiones previas, hacer "ramificaciones" (experimentos en los que pruebas a cambiar cosas en otra "historia paralela", sin perder la historia original) y muchas más cosas que se salen de los objetivos de esta respuesta.

Para llevar ese histórico, Git simplemente crea una carpeta especial en tu propio ordenador, y allí va guardando la información que necesita para hacer ese seguimiento. Todo queda en tu propio ordenador por defecto.

**"Distribuido"** significa que si varios programadores trabajan en el mismo proyecto, cada uno tiene su propia copia del repositorio, en su ordenador local. La colaboración entre programadores es posible, si bien compleja, mediante comandos especiales de git para extraer cambios del histórico y enviarlos por email a otros desarrolladores.

La posibilidad de tener una copia más del repositorio en otro lugar ("en la nube"), accesible para todos quienes trabajan en el proyecto, simplifica mucho la colaboración, pues cada uno puede cada cierto tiempo "sincronizar" su copia local con la compartida por todos.

Esa copia "en la nube" es útil aún si trabajas solo, pues puede servir como *backup* en caso de desastre en tu ordenador local. De vez en cuando sincronizas tu repositorio local con el remoto para asegurarte de que tus progresos están a salvo. En caso de desastre de la máquina, una vez te hayas comprado otra, puedes recuperar el repositorio remoto y seguir trabajando. También te sirve por si trabajas desde diferentes ordenadores, para asegurarte de que los cambios que hagas en uno sean visibles en otros ("subirías" los cambios mediante una operación denominada `push` y los "bajarías" en los demás mediante `pull`).

Gitllab, Github y Bitbucket son servidores que te ofrecen esta posibilidad (guardar en la nube una copia de tus repositorios, ya sea para uso privado o para compartirlo con otros, o con el mundo entero).

Git y estos servidores han revolucionado el mundo del Open Source, al hacer muy sencillo para cualquiera colaborar con proyectos de otros, por el método de descargar una copia del repositorio de otro (si es público) para hacer cambios locales (lo que se denomina un *fork*), y luego darle al propietario del repositorio original la posibilidad de examinar nuestros cambios e incorporarlos al suyo (lo que se llama un *pull request*).